# Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code

Tags: python, algorithm

I am a beginner coder and would just like to say thanks for the help.  I probably made some rookie mistakes but that's why I'm here to learn. I cant figure out what's wrong but lets say I plug in a string (50,K,C) it should convert 50 Kelvin to Celsius but my code does nothing

```
def temperature_converter(value, scale_from, scale_to):

    if scale_from == "F" and scale_to == "C":
        (value -32)* 5 / 9 for F to C
        return
    elif scale_from == "F" and scale_to == "K":
        (value * 5 / 9) + 273 for F to K
        return
    elif scale_from == "C" and scale_to == "F":
        value * (9 / 5) + 32  for C to F
        return
    elif scale_from == "C" and scale_to == "K":
        (value + 273) for C to K
        return
    elif scale_from == "K" and scale_to == "F":
        9/5 * (value - 273) + 32 for K to F
        return
    elif scale_from == "K" and scale_to == "C":
        value - 273 for  K to F
        return
```

Comment: Please provide the calling code, and fix the indentation to *reflect what you actually have*, indentation has meaningin Python. The easiest way: copy-and-paste directly form your editor, then highlight and press ctrl-k.

Comment: `value * (9 / 5) + 32  for C to F` that's not even valid python.

Comment: 1. You aren't calling the function; which 2. doesn't actually make sense.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve when you do `for C to F` etc?

Comment: python comments start with # `#for  K to F`

Comment: `return  (value + 273) #for C to K` might be what you want for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, lets take it bit by bit:

1. `for F to C` and other similar "statements" you have in your code are not valid python. Plus, they seem to serve no purpose, so I have removed them below.
2. Operations performed on variables are not done in-place. When you do `(value -32)* 5 / 9`, you must store that result somewhere. `value` will remain the same throughout, unless you assign a value to it.
3. When you `return`, you have to return *something*. Just having the `return` keyword there doesn't do anything.

Here is a revised version of your code. I have deliberately made the first and second case (F to C, F to K) more verbose to illustrate point 2:

```
def temperature_converter(value, scale_from, scale_to):
    if scale_from == "F" and scale_to == "C":
        a = (value -32)* 5 / 9 #Assign the modified value to a variable
        return a
    elif scale_from == "F" and scale_to == "K":
        value = (value * 5 / 9) + 273 #The value variable can be reused
        return value
    elif scale_from == "C" and scale_to == "F":
        return value * (9 / 5) + 32 #Always return something. Don't have just the keyword
    elif scale_from == "C" and scale_to == "K":
        return value + 273
    elif scale_from == "K" and scale_to == "F":
        return 9/5 * (value - 273) + 32 
    elif scale_from == "K" and scale_to == "C":
        return value - 273
```

A couple of extra points:

- It is advisable to bunch up your cases, as I will demonstrate below. IMO it makes for more readable code.
- You should always standardize your input. Take the possibility of the user entering `"f"` in lowercase into account in this case.
- Account for being given bogus arguments.

Final code would be:

```
def temperature_converter(value, scale_from, scale_to):
    scale_from = scale_from.upper() #Make all arguments upper case
    scale_to = scale_to.upper() 

    if scale_from == "F": #Group cases together
        if scale_to == "C":
            return (value -32)* 5 / 9
        elif scale_to == "K":
            return (value * 5 / 9) + 273
    elif scale_from == "C":
        if scale_to == "F":
            return value * (9 / 5) + 32
        elif scale_to == "K":
            return value + 273
    elif scale_from == "K":
        if scale_to == "F":
            return 9/5 * (value - 273) + 32
        elif scale_to == "K":
            return value - 273

    raise ValueError("Invalid argument") #Have predictable behavior if invalid input is given
```

Comment: You can Have just one `return` statement and can store results in a single variable. Isn't that be more pythonic instead of having **five return** statements for a single function.

Comment: As long as everything is concise, I don't see a problem with multiple returns. It comes down to personal preference. But if we really wanted to condense OP's code, there are other ways (i.e. using a dictionary).

Comment: In general, when dealing with conversions between `n` units, dealing with every possible conversion requires O(n^2) code paths. Instead, pick an intermediate unit (which does not necessarily have to be one of actual units), and define only conversions between the intermediary and the targets. This only requires O(n) code paths. In this case, just use K as the intermediary; convert any input to Kelvin (if necessary), then convert the Kelvin to the final target (if necessary). This avoids having to convert Celsius directly to Fahrenheit, for example.

Answer (score 0):

We might as well give to the correct conversion formulas while you're here

```
def temperature_converter(value, scale_from, scale_to) :

    if scale_from == "F" and scale_to == "C" :
        return (value - 32.0) * 5 / 9 #for F to C
    elif scale_from == "F" and scale_to == "K":
        return (value + 459.67) * 5 / 9 #for F to K
    elif scale_from == "C" and scale_to == "F":
        return value * (9.0 / 5.0) + 32  #for C to F
    elif scale_from == "C" and scale_to == "K":
        return value + 273.15 #for C to K
    elif scale_from == "K" and scale_to == "F":
        return ((value - 273.15) * 1.8) + 32 #for K to F
    elif scale_from == "K" and scale_to == "C":
        return value - 273.15 #for  K to C
```

Then call it like this

```
result = temperature_converter(50, "F", "C")
```

or this

```
result = temperature_converter(50, 'F', 'C')
```

I think you might have been calling the function wrong, as well.

There is a very important thing that you might not know, and nobody here told you yet.  It could potentially cause you major headaches trying figure out why you are getting the wrong values.

There are *integers* and *floating point* numbers (or *floats*).  To put it simply, *integers* are whole numbers, but *floats* can use decimals and fractional values.

If you use only integers it will round the values to a whole number.  I noticed this in a big way with the Celsius to Fahrenheit conversion.  When I used 9 / 5 instead of 9.0 / 5.0, it rounded the value a lot, and my answer was way off.   This is because it was rounding 9 / 5 to a whole number, instead of 9 / 5 = 1.8.

So keep that in mind.  Make sure your Python interpreter is using *floats* (decimal values) in the way you're expecting, and it's doing the math the way you want.

I included decimal points in all the formulas, so Python was using *floats* for the math. (At least my Python interpreter was.)

Also, double check the formulas.

Edit:

Don't forget to print your answer

```
print(result)
```